# Java Graphics.drawImage() isn't drawing at right position

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, draw

```
JFrame m = new JFrame();
    
m.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512, 448));
m.setResizable(false);
m.pack();
m.setVisible(true);
 
BufferedImage img = null;
try
{
    title = ImageIO.read(new File("data\\img.bmp"));
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while (true)
{   
    Graphics g = m.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

This is drawing the image at a 26 pixel offset on the Y axis. X axis is fine, but it looks like pushed up under the title bar.

The image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HEmZYBW.png]

What I get:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bXcnNW1.png]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing directly to the JFrame, I just extended Component, added it to the JFrame, and drew to it.